# Paypal Express + New Customer + Onestep Checkout = no taxes applied on order

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, paypal-express

I'm having an issue on my Magento 1.7 that is related to this one ([Paypal Express not including Tax with OneStepCheckout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4429/paypal-express-not-including-tax-with-onestepcheckout)) but it's not the same. In that case, the total is incorrect in paypal, in my case, the totals are correct in paypal, but the new order in magento doesn't include any taxes. These are the steps to reproduce and the problems I have:

- Non registered customer adds a product to the basket and goes to checkout (onestepcheckout)
- Customer introduces all the data, including passwords (it's mandatory to register before purchasing)
- Selects Paypal Express and proceeds with the payment.
- In Paypal window, the totals are correct (product price + taxes)
- Payment is OK and the customer returns to the website

Errors:

1. When the customer goes to his account, the order total doesn't include any taxes
2. The customer is assigned to the group 'Not logged in', even though it's registered during the checkout

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please contact extension support, they will solve this for you

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation I found that when the class

```
app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
```

creates the new user, it doesn't assign it to any group. The result is the problem I described below.

The solution is simple then:

· Rewrite that class:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <paypal>
            <rewrite> 
                <express_checkout>Bqreaders_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout</express_checkout>
            </rewrite>
        </paypal>
    </models>
</global>
```

· Rewrite the function _prepareNewCustomerQuote(). Just add:

```
    $customer->setGroupId(Mage::getStoreConfig('customer/create_account/default_group'));
```

At the section where it sets all the customer data.